# Closing stream after using BitmapEncoder with WinJS Metro app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

In a Windows 8 Metro application written in JS I open a file, get the stream, write some image data to it using the 'promise - .then' pattern.  It works fine - the file is successfully saved to the file system, except after using the BitmapEncoder to flush the stream to the file, the stream is still open. ie; I can't access the file until I kill the application, but the 'stream' variable is out of scope for me to reference, so I can't close() it. Is there something comparable to the C# using statement that could be used?

```
...then(function (file) {
                return file.openAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.readWrite);
            })
.then(function (stream) {
                //Create imageencoder object
                return Imaging.BitmapEncoder.createAsync(Imaging.BitmapEncoder.pngEncoderId, stream);
            })
.then(function (encoder) {
                //Set the pixel data in the encoder ('canvasImage.data' is an existing image stream)
                encoder.setPixelData(Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.rgba8, Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.straight, canvasImage.width, canvasImage.height, 96, 96, canvasImage.data);
                //Go do the encoding
                return encoder.flushAsync();
                //file saved successfully, 
                //but stream is still open and the stream variable is out of scope.
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [simple imaging sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Simple-Imaging-Sample-a2dec2b0) from Microsoft might help. Copied below.

It looks like, in your case, you need to declare the stream before the chain of `then` calls, make sure you don't name-collide with your parameter to your function accepting the stream (note the part where they do `_stream = stream`), and add a `then` call to close the stream.

```
function scenario2GetImageRotationAsync(file) { 
    var accessMode = Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.read; 

    // Keep data in-scope across multiple asynchronous methods 
    var stream; 
    var exifRotation;
    return file.openAsync(accessMode).then(function (_stream) { 
        stream = _stream; 
        return Imaging.BitmapDecoder.createAsync(stream); 
    }).then(function (decoder) { 
        // irrelevant stuff to this question
    }).then(function () { 
        if (stream) { 
            stream.close(); 
        } 
        return exifRotation; 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It seems that if there's an error thrown anywhere in the 1st or 2nd `then`, it would make stream closing code not to execute. The last `then` should have error handler which closes stream as well.